# horizontal scrolling with 100% image-height

Tags: html, css, resize

Im currently building a horizontal scrolling portfolio. I want the images to be 100% high and width:auto. Everything works perfectly (pure CSS), but if the browser window gets smaller than the image width, it gets compressed.

Here is the link: http://www.bastards-design.de/wordpress/category/allgemein/portfolio/grafik/#alina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the browser window gets smaller than the image width, it gets compressed.

I've looked through your code and found the following CSS in it, which causes the images to compress. If you remove it, the images would not compress.

```
img{
   max-width:100%;
}
```

Seems like this rule is being inherited from **bootstrap.ccs** you are using. You should remove this rule or override it.

Comment: Thank you! I saw that but I didnt expect its removal to cause a different behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove `max-width` from `bootstrap.css`
you have currently as below:

```
img {
    border: 0 none;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

not try removing `max-width: 100%;` as below:

```
img {
    border: 0 none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

this should work.